# How do I make an User required JSON

Tags: python-2.7

I have a JSON file, in that three objects are available, In that 2nd and 3rd objects does not have some fields which I actually needed. In missing fields, I need to add my own values. I will provide my code below

## I tried this So far:

```
with open("final.json") as data1:
    a = json.load(data1)
final = []
for item in a:
    d = {}
    d["AppName"]= item["name"]
    d["AppId"] = item["id"]
    d["Health"] = item["health"]
    d["place1"] = item["cities"][0]["place1"]
    d["place2"] = item["cities"][0]["place2"]
print(final)
```

Error:  I am getting Key Error

## My Input JSON file has similar data:

```
[{
                "name": "python",
                "id": 1234,
                "health": "Active",
                "cities": {
                        "place1": "us",
                        "place2": "newyork"
                }
        },
        {
                "name": "java",
                "id": 2345,
                "health": "Active"
        }, {
                "name": "python",
                "id": 1234

        }
]
```

## I am expecting output:

```
[{
                "name": "python",
                "id": 1234,
                "health": "Active",
                "cities": {
                        "place1": "us",
                        "place2": "newyork"
                }
        },
        {
                "name": "java",
                "id": 2345,
                "health": "Null",
                "cities": {
                        "place1": "0",
                        "place2": "0"
                }
        }, {
                "name": "python",
                "id": 1234,
                "health": "Null",
                "cities": {
                        "place1": "0",
                        "place2": "0"
                }

        }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with the code that you have posted.

First, you are referring to the 'cities' field in you input JSON as if it is a list when it is, in fact, an object.

Second, to handle JSON containing objects which may be missing certain fields, you should use the Python dictionary [get](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) method. This method takes a key and an optional value to return if the key is not found (default is None).

```
for item in a:
    d = {}
    d["AppName"]= item["name"]
    d["AppId"] = item["id"]
    d["Health"] = item.get("health", "Null")
    d["place1"] = item.get("cities", {}).get("place1", "0")
    d["place2"] = item.get("cities", {}).get("place2", "0")
```